# R: Use unzip to extract raster that is downloaded to a temporary file

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to download worldclim gridded climate data to a temporary file and then open it as a raster. I do not want to save the files to my computer. I can do this with zipfiles that contain only one gridded climate dataset but I can not seem to get this to work when there are many.

Thanks in advance.

```
temp <- tempfile()
#download worldclim climate data
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/worldclim/1_4/grid/cur/tmean_10m_esri.zip",temp, mode="wb")
unzip(temp,list=TRUE)#list files
#unzip and make raster, may need this as seperate steps
meanT<- raster(unzip(paste0(temp,"/tmean/tmean_9")))
unlink(temp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution; unzip the downloaded temporary file to a temporary directory.

```
temp <- tempfile()
tempd <- tempdir()

#download worldclim climate data
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/worldclim/1_4/grid/cur/tmean_10m_esri.zip",temp, mode="wb")

unzip(temp, exdir=tempd)
tmean_raster <- raster(file.path(tempd, "tmean/tmean_9"))
unlink(tempd)
```

Answer (score 1):

A direct way to get these data is:

```
library(raster)
wc <- getData('worldclim', var='tmean', res=10)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although this is a much more direct way to get the data from worldclim, the other method will work for data from many websites and can be modified based on the list of files that is returned.